# Use a struct in a header file [ C - Linux ]

Tags: c, linux, struct, xdr

I tried to use an external struct but when I compile my c code I obtained this message:

`subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector`.

Why?

messaggio.h

```
struct Request {
    struct {
        u_int data_len;
        float *data_val;
    } data;
    bool_t last;
};
typedef struct Request Request;
```

main.c

```
#include "messaggio.h"

int main(void){
 struct Request x;
 x.data[0] = 4.6;
 printf("%f\n",x.data[0]);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x.data` is a struct, so you cannot use `[]` with it. Maybe you want `x.data.data_val[0]`.

Try this code:

```
struct Request x;
x.data.data_len = 5; // initialize the length, use any value you need
x.data.data_val = (float *) malloc(x.data.data_len * sizeof(float));
x.data.data_val[0] = 4.6
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm goig to accept your answer. But why I obtain: segmentation fault error?

Comment: You have to malloc memory to x.data.data_val before you reference it. When you define a pointer, the pointer contains a random value, so when you reference to a random pointer, it's very possible to get a core dump.

Answer (score 0):

`x.data` is a structure and not an array.

Use `x.data.data_val[0]` if that is what you are trying to access.  However, you have not allocated any memory for `data_val`.  I believe you are trying to assign a number to `data_len` and will need to allocate the memory to hold `data_len` values in `data_val`.

Answer (score 0):

The type of struct Request#data is an anonymous struct { u_int, float } and not an array. Thus you can't use the [] operator on it.

You probably wanted to do:

```
x.data.data_val[0]
```